# Change ip addr label in Linux

Tags: linux, networking

How can I change the eth0 zero to eth0:1 using ip addr without deleting. 
When I run

```
ip addr show eth0
```

Here is the output

```
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet X.X.X.Y/24 brd X.X.X.255 scope global eth0
    inet 10.10.10.17/32 scope global eth0
    inet6 XX::XX:XX:XX:XX/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I want this to look like without deleting interface.

```
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet X.X.X.Y/24 brd X.X.X.255 scope global eth0
    inet 10.10.10.17/32 scope global eth0:1
    inet6 XX::XX:XX:XX:XX/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How can I just change label?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no modification.  You have to delete and add.

Comment: How about to use `ip link set dev <interface> name eth0:1`  but says interface is in use.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do?  Why do you think you need to to be eth0:1 anyway?  I am not aware of any advantage to doing this.

Comment: I have virtual ip assigned to eth0 using ip addr, trying to make it compatible. So that, I can use the ifconfig down and up for that. With out causing any outage.

Comment: If you use `ifconfig down` it is going to stop the device, not just one pseudo-interface with a particular address.  So lets dig deeper, why do you think you need to regularly stop & start an interface?

Comment: This is a High Availability server, I don't want to stop the process as it is running all the critical services. With out affecting any services, if I am able to make it compatible with ifconfig our failovers are easy. (We use ucarp for failovers). To make that change I am trying not to have any downtime (even for 1 min).

Answer (score 3):

for IPv4, this works:

```
ip addr add 10.10.10.17/32 dev eth0 label eth0:1
```